# Databricks Connect 13.3: Could not find connection parameters to start a Spark remote session

Tags: databricks-connect

I use `databricks connect v11` and try to use it now for `v13`. So I do the follwing:

```
pip install -U "databricks-connect==13.3.3"
```

Then I run

```
       echo "y
       https://adb-xxx.7.azuredatabricks.net
       xxxx-2
       yyyy
       zzz
       15001" | databricks-connect configure
```

Then I run 
`python3 -m pytest` whereby one file uses `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` which results in the following error:

> RuntimeError: Only remote Spark sessions using Databricks Connect are
> supported. Could not find connection parameters to start a Spark
> remote session.

**EDIT**: I also run:

```
export SPARK_REMOTE="sc://adb-xxxx.7.azuredatabricks.net:15001/;token=xxx-2;x-databricks-clus
ter-id=xxx"
```

which didn't work either.

In the home directory a valid `.databricks-connect` file is existing

Obviously, some config step is missing which was not necessary for v11

Comment: I am facing the same issue when using 13.3, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No I didn't: I researched but no solution so far